# How old is this cat

Tags: mathematics

If the mother's age was 2,
and if the grandfather's age is 6, 
and if the father's age is the grandfather's minus the mother's + 1,
And the cat's age is the father's age - the mother's age, how old is this cat?

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward algebra problem, is there anything about it that I'm missing that brings it into the puzzling realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mother = 2
> Grandfather = 6
> Father = 5 -> (G - M + 1) 6 - 2 + 1 = 5
> The Cat = 3 -> (F - M) 5 - 2

So I would say the cat is

> 3 years old

But that seems easy, so I'm most likely missing something? With the "was 2", I guess.

Comment: This causes the cat to be older than the mother, which is.. interesting, to say the least. Another possibility is that the father's age is "the grandfather's minus (the mother's plus one)", making it 6-3 = 3, and that the cat's age is 3 - 2 = 1

Comment: @Votbear which makes sense, and would make me say "Oh! I'm dumb, that's more logical" except...my answer was accepted. SOoo I don't know what to think tbh.

Comment: Exactly, that made me confused too lol. Oh well.

Comment: heh whoops. I honestly forgot this existed. *I was dumber back then*